# How to convert str to int with default value

Tags: python, lambda

I have variable d int.

```
d = int(input("1 - to enter expression; 2 - to enter text; 3 - to exit. "))
```

But if you do not enter a number then the program crashes with an error. To avoid this I write this:

```
d = (lambda x = input("1 - to enter expression; 2 - to enter text; 3 - to exit. "): int(x) if x.isdigit() else: 3)
```

but get an error

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = input("1 - to enter expression; 2 - to enter text; 3 - to exit. ")
try:
    d = int(d)
except ValueError:
    d = 3  # the default value
```